# SKSpriteNode fall off the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Can some body help me, I created a `SpriteKit` ​node called(`player`) and once I set its physics it fall off the screen​:

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "car")
player.position.x = -300
player.zPosition = 1
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.size)
player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 1
addChild(player)
```

I already tried adding

```
affectedByGravity
```

but the same result for the player and the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, you want your car not to be effected by gravity.
If it is so you might want to setup the physics of your "world", like:

```
    func setWorld() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        //This should do the trick!
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0, dy:0)

        //This is useful if you want to create wall along the borders    
        let frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        //here you set the borders as walls
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

        physicsBody?.friction = 0
        physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    }
```

and call this function in didMove

Comment: Noooooo that turns off gravity for the entire world, not just the car.  Just set `isAffectedByGravity = false` on the physics body